# How do I keep icons aligned in multiple rows in a ChakraUI Flexbox container?

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, flexbox, chakra-ui

I am making a simple video game discovery app as a personal project to get better at using React. I am having an issue aligning these icons inside the game card. The icons represent each platform that a given game is available on.

At first, I was having an issue with the icons overflowing, specifically on the game cards where there are many icons. I got them to stop overflowing by using flexWrap, however, now the icons arent aligned properly if there is more than one row of icons. The max each row can take is 6 icons. I know technically I could make the icons smaller for a quick workaround, but I would prefer to leave the icons the size they are at right now as they are already pretty small.

Relevant code:

```
  <HStack flexWrap='wrap' display="flex" justify='space-between' marginY={1}>
        {platforms.map((platform) => (
          <Icon
            as={iconMap[platform.slug]}
            boxSize="1em"
            color="gray.500"
          ></Icon>
        ))}
   </HStack>
```

Icons:
[Misaligned row of icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BmaqW.png)

I am using ChakraUI. I am sure there is something simple I am overlooking but I have tried using every flex property I can think of and nothing is working. I would like to make each row of icons align with each other, if a second row of icons is needed.

Answer (score 0):

I know two possibilites to fix this:

**Update to a more recent version of Chakra UI**
In the editable stack example on the Chakra UI website your issue is only reproducible with [`v1.8.8`](https://v1.chakra-ui.com/docs/components/layout/stack#usage) but not with [`v2.8.0`](https://chakra-ui.com/docs/components/layout/stack#usage):

```
<HStack flexWrap='wrap'>
  {Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, index) => (
    <Box key={index} w='40px' h='40px' bg='tomato'>
      box
    </Box>
  ))}
</HStack>
```

**Set spacing to 0 and use columnGap instead**
To fix the issue on an older version of Chakra UI or to fix the spacing of a `ButtonGroup` element (which is still broken in `v2.8.0`) the default `spacing={2}` can be overwritten with `0` and `columnGap={2}` can be used instead:

```
<HStack flexWrap='wrap' spacing='0' columnGap={2} >
  {Array.from({ length: 20 }, (_, index) => (
    <Box key={index} w='40px' h='40px' bg='tomato'>
      box
    </Box>
  ))}
</HStack>
```

[image: Example of boxes without and with the fix]